# All Ajax calls have stopped working on website

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a MVC site that has a lot of client side coding thanks to Kendo UI involvement and View designs. I just realized after a while that all of my ajax calls are not functioning. All cascading dropdowns have stopped working. Grids are not fetching results. Everything is just showing the loading animation.

Here is a sample code that retrieves a couple of values after a user enters a company id in a Kendo NumericTextBox and tabs out:

```
$(function () {
$("#CompanyId").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        return;
    }

    $("#CompanyCategory").val("Loading...").addClass("disabled");
    $("#CompanyName").val("Loading...").addClass("disabled");

    $.post(BASE_URL + "Ajax/CompanyById", { companyId: $("#CompanyId").val() },
        function (response) {
            console.log('CompanyId.Blur call completed: ' + response.result);
            $("#CompanyCategory").val((response.result.CategoryNameEnglish));
            $("#CompanyName").val((response.result.NameEnglish));
        }
    ).fail(
        function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error in CompanyId.Blur');
            console.log(' > xmlHttpRequest: ' + xmlHttpRequest);
            console.log(' > textStatus: ' + textStatus);
            console.log(' > errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);

            $("#CompanyCategory").val("");
            $("#CompanyName").val("");
            $("#CompanyCategory").val("Loading...").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#CompanyName").val("Loading...").removeClass("disabled");
        });
   });
});
```

I have put in some console logging and it never triggers. The two textboxes show "Loading..." as per the code but once the execution reached the `$.post()`, everything goes to pending status. Chrome/IE Debug Tool's Console show nothing and Network shows call made but just pending and never returns.

I do not receive any breakpoint-hit on the AjaxController.

Any guess why this is broken up?

I'm using jQuery 2.2.4

Thanks!

Comment: seems a server side problem

Comment: Do a server restart and try again! Furthermore, there could be a DB table lock where, requests hang! Might help restarting the server!

Comment: I'm also looking at it as a server side. I'm in dev mode: IIS express for site and the service it uses. Local DB. All break-point ready to hit but nothing happens.

Comment: Restarting Workstation has no effect. Behavior is consistent in IE, Chrome, and Firefox. Anything that enters a `$.post()` never comes back and goes to an infinite pending state. The Url and the controller action names are all consistent and this was working perfectly. I'm looking at check ins now to see if something critical was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of the way Kendo was setup. Somehow, my own jQuery 2.2.4 and Kendo's jQuery 1.x both got initialized and neither was working at runtime. The whole jQuery was messing up.